# Vanishing theorems on toric DM stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties, algebraic-stacks, vanishing

In chapter 9 of the book *Toric varieties* by Cox-Little-Schenck several cohomology vanishing theorems for toric varieties are proved or mentioned.

In this question I am interested in references for versions (if existing) of the analogous vanishing theorems for toric Deligne-Mumford stacks (especially the smooth ones, e.g. in the sense of [Fantechi-Mann-Nironi](http://www.math.univ-montp2.fr/%7Emann/Fantechi-Mann-Nironi-Crelle.pdf)). I am happy with assuming we are over $\mathbb{C}$ and the stacks have trivial generic stabilizer.

**Edit.** To answer the question of Jason Starr in the comments, I think I am mostly interested in a stacky version of Batyrev-Borisov vanishing theorem, which I am reporting below. Nevertheless, I would also be glad to receive answers about the other vanishing theorems that I mentioned or alluded to in my question.

> **Theorem (Batyrev-Borisov).** Let $X=X_{\Sigma}$ be a complete toric variety, and $D=\sum_{\rho\in\Sigma(1)} a_\rho D_\rho$ a nef $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier divisor on $X$. Then
>
> $$H^p(X,\mathcal{O}(-D))=0\;\;\;\;\forall\; p\neq \dim P_D,$$
> $$H^{\dim P_D}(X,\mathcal{O}(-D))=\bigoplus_{m\in \mathrm{relint}(P_D)\cap M}\mathbb{C}\cdot \chi^{-m},$$
> where $M$ is the lattice of $\Sigma$ and $P_D$ is a polytope defined by
>
> $$P_D=\{ x \in M \otimes\mathbb{R}\;|\; \langle x,u_{\rho} \rangle \leq -a_{\rho} \; \forall \; \rho\in\Sigma (1)\}$$
> $u_{\rho}$ being the minimal generator of the ray $\rho$.

Comment: Could you state one of the vanishing theorems you would like for a toric Deligne-Mumford stack?  For instance, Olsson-Matsuki have an extension of Kodaira vanishing to stacks (and they use this to reprove many case of Kawamata-Viehweg vanishing for usual varieties).

Comment: I think I do not understand what you mean.  For the toric boundary $\Delta$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$, $h^1(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}(-\Delta))$ is nonzero.

Comment: Right. Just deleted my previous comment.

Comment: Could you please state the vanishing theorem that you would like to extend to toric Deligne-Mumford stacks?

Comment: In characteristic $0$, pushforward from the toric Deligne-Mumford stack to the coarse moduli space toric variety is an exact functor that has vanishing higher direct images.  Thus, it seems to me that, via Leray-Serre, Batyrev-Borisov vanishing for the toric Deligne-Mumford stack reduces to Batyrev-Borisov vanishing for the coarse moduli space toric variety.

Comment: @J.S.  I thought: since $\mathcal{X}$ has to be a root construction over a canonical stack, if I'm not getting confused, I think one can easily reduce things to canonical stacks. Then, I have to think how to do it for canonical stacks... But at this point it's probably as difficult to do it in one step as you suggest.

Comment: If this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/223453/question-about-canonical-dm-stacks has a positive answer then I think I'm done.